# Value is not binding in mat-select drop-down if it is an object

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, mean-stack

I am using Angular Material.

The issue issue is with `mat-select`. It is not binding the value on edit of record.

Here is my code..

**HTML**

Here as you can see I bound `test.subject`(an object) in the model and showing `subject.title` in the drop-down as a text.

```
   <mat-form-field>
     <mat-select [(ngModel)]="test.subject" placeholder="Subject" name="subject">
       <mat-option>--</mat-option>
       <mat-option *ngFor="let subject of subjects" [value]="subject">
         {{subject.title}}
       </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
```

**Component**

In the component, I got this value from the database.

```
this.test = {
   "subject": {
       "_id": "5b3883b4067d8d2744871eff",
       "title": "Subject 1"
    }
}

this.subjects = [
   {
       "_id": "5b3883b4067d8d2744871eff",
       "title": "Subject 1"
   },{
        "_id": "5b3843b4067d8d2744435erx",
        "title": "Subject 2"
   }
]
```

So here I am expecting the drop down should be selected with value `Subject 1`.  But it is not.

Comment: I think you need to use ngModel.

Comment: I have used ngModel.

Comment: this will not binding you have to set value instead of **Object**  because **Object==Object** always returns false thats why it's not binding..!!

Comment: @Sanoj_V I am from the angularjs background. And in angularjs it works fine. So I think this is not the case. There shall a way to do this in the angular 6 as well.

Comment: is this what you are trying for? [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h16x7b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Hey @Avinash test.subject._id will not change in this case.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya this should work `[(ngModel)]="test.subject._id"` and your [value] should be`<mat-option *ngFor="let subject of subjects" [value]="subject._id">`. i changed in the demo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hi @Surjeet Bhadauriya

You can try with this solution.

I have create a demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/value-is-not-binding-in-mat-select-drop-down-if-it-is-an-object)

use `[compareWith]="compareObjects"` for use object in `mat-select`

> component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [compareWith]="compareObjects" [(ngModel)]="test.subject" placeholder="Subject" name="subject">
        <mat-option>--</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let subject of subjects" [value]="subject">
            {{subject.title}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

> component.ts

```
test: any;
subjects: Array<any>;

compareObjects(o1: any, o2: any): boolean {
    return o1.name === o2.name && o1._id === o2._id;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much @Krishna, can you please explain how and why this works ?